# How to get vales of application.prpoperty in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to access some values from my `application.properties` file, I tried using below method but not getting value.

**application.property file**

`welcome.message=My message`

**Mycontroller.java**

```java
@RestController
class MessageRestController {
    @Autowired MainConfigFiles mainConfigFiles;
      
      @Value("${welcome.message}") 
      private String message;

      @RequestMapping("/message") 
      String getMessage() { 
          return this.message; 
      }

      @RequestMapping("/message2") 
      String getMessage2() { 
          MainConfigFiles a = new MainConfigFiles();
          String msg = a.getMessage2();
          System.out.println("Msg is....."+msg);
          return msg; 
      }
```

**MainConfigFiles.java**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "application.properties")
public class MainConfigFiles {
    
     @Value("${welcome.message}") 
     private String message2;
     
    public String getMessage2() {
        return message2;
    }
}
```

I am able to get the value using
`@RequestMapping("/message")`  which is mentioned in the same file but unable to get the value when using `@RequestMapping("/message2")` which mentioned in another class.

Comment: You should request "mainconfigfiles" as a "bean"  ...not via `new`. So: Delete `a`, and use `mainConfigFiles.getMessage2()` instead.

Comment: And I am running a config client on this same project and the value from application.propertie is not refreshing after running POST req on http://localhost:8080/actuator/refresh

Comment: Please answer/accept/[edit] this... or raise a new question! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to read the welcome.message value from application.properties file and set it to MainConfigFiles. Later use this MainConfigFiles class(that you are already using @Autowire) and get that message.

Modify MainConfigFiles class as below.

```
public class MainConfigFiles {

Value("${welcome.message}")
private String message2;

Bean
public MainConfigFiles jpaConfig() {

    MainConfigFiles mainConfigFiles = new MainConfigFiles();
    mainConfigFiles.setMessage2(message2);
    return mainConfigFiles;
}

public String getMessage2() {
    return message2;
}

public void setMessage2(String message2) {
    this.message2 = message2;
}
}
```

This is your MessageRestController.

```
@RestController
public class MessageRestController {

@Autowired
private MainConfigFiles mainConfigFiles;

@Value("${welcome.message}")
private String message;

@RequestMapping("/message")
String getMessage() {
    return this.message;
}

@RequestMapping("/message2")
String getMessage2() {
    String msg = mainConfigFiles.getMessage2();
    System.out.println("Msg is....."+msg);
    return msg;
}
}
```

Note- While using @Value annotation we need to be a little careful otherwise [using @Value you may not able to read data](https://javatute.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-value-not-working/) from application.proprties.

Comment: Check more examples https://javatute.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-value-annotation-example/.